# Kafka one consumer one partition

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a use case where I have a single topic with 100 partitions where messages go in each partition with some logic and I have 100 consumers who reads this message. I want to map a specific partition to a specific consumer. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the [Javadoc](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) for the KafkaConsumer, specifically the section "Manual Partition Assignment".

**TL/DR**

You can manually assign specific partitions to a consumer as follows:

```java
String topic = "foo";
TopicPartition partition0 = new TopicPartition(topic, 0);
TopicPartition partition1 = new TopicPartition(topic, 1);
consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(partition0, partition1));
```